# With mod_rewrite, how do you redirect only images that were stored at the root level to a subdirectory?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site that stored all their images at the root level. I'd like to move the images to a sub directory such as /media/images and then with mod_rewrite, direct all requests for those images stored at the root level to the ones that have been moved to the directory /media/images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(\.png|\.jpg|\.bmp|\.gif)$ media/images/$1$2`

Should work nicely.